# Can Haskell be used to write shell scripts?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, haskell

Is it possible to write shell scripts in Haskell and if so, how do you do it? Just changing the interpreter like so?

```
#!/bin/ghci
```

Comment: Probably `#!/usr/bin/gchci` or `#!/usr/bin/env ghci` - but then it is an Haskell script, not a shell one.

Comment: Look at this question. It should give you a lot of information. 'Is Clojure or Haskell better for making command line tools?' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997003

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Using `ghci` will just load the module in GHCi. To run it as a script, use `runhaskell` or `runghc`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 13):

Well check this presentation : [Practical Haskell: scripting with types](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/practical-haskell/)

Answer (score 11):

It should work if you change the interpreter to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/runhaskell
```

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the path, in general it is better to use `#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell` the way @Hammar suggests so that `runhaskell` can be found anywhere in your path instead of just in `/usr/bin`. Many people do not install Haskell at the system level, so you cannot rely on always finding it at that location.

Answer (score 5):

As of October 2016, there is a better answer to this question: use [The Haskell Tool Stack script interpreter](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter). `stack`-based Haskell scripts are portable because they download (and cache) the correct version of `ghc` and all of their package dependencies.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-3.2 --install-ghc runghc
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

See also the tutorial [How to Script with Stack](https://ci.haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to write shell scripts using Haskell is to generate the scripts, such as with [bashkell](https://github.com/solidsnack/bash/tree/master/hs). This is useful if you might want to run on systems that do not have haskell installed.